# MySQL - wrapping multiple procedure calls in a transaction

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, procedure

I'm trying to wrap multiple calls in a single transaction. Let's suppose I have 2 procedures: `spOuter` and `spInner`.

`spInner` is a very long procedure. Depending on the parameters passed, it may do inserts, updates, and deletes. `spInner` does not start new transactions, and it does not commit or rollback anything by itself.

`spOuter` simply calls `spInner` inside a transaction (in this example, while in the real code it calls spInner multiple times with different parameters):

```sql
sp: BEGIN

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
END;

START TRANSACTION;

-- Call spInner (@oReturnCode is an output parameter)
CALL spInner(@someParameter, @oReturnCode);

-- if spInner returns anything other than 0, I want to rollback its changes
IF (@oReturnCode != 0) THEN 
    ROLLBACK;
    LEAVE sp;
END IF;

-- Do other stuff

COMMIT;
END
```

However, when spInner fails and sets @oReturnCode to a non-zero value, the ROLLBACK command has no effect on whatever was modified by it.

Comment: could you add complete declarations of your minimal spInner and spOuter that demonstrate the problem?

Comment: and create table statements